# Uikit dynamic density

Tags: objective-c, xcode, dynamic, uikit

i'm trying to make a barrier in uikit dynamic sso this barrier don't get affected by gravity but when a object hits it it start floating instead of keeping in place and stop the object, I was planing to set a high density but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question with you. but i cant find the correct answer.if you want wo use UIDynamic to creat barrier,that the better thing is to create a barrier to add below behavior.

```
UIDynamicItemBehavior itemBehaviorNoBounce = [[UIDynamicItemBehavior alloc] init];
itemBehaviorNoBounce.allowsRotation = NO;
itemBehaviorNoBounce.elasticity = 0;
```

this can make the item collision a little, but if you have a lot of thing to crash，that is a not good way to use UIDynamic for a barrier. beacause the calculate of the item is complex. And you cant control it.